# State of Legal Residence - is this person filing taxes right?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

I have a friend who left home at 18 to join the Marines.  He used his parents' address for mail.  He then worked for various overseas companies (doing oil related things) and continued to use his parents' address for mail, tax forms, and employer records.  Now he lives in the US again, but in a different state than his parents.  He says that since he moves every year or two, his parents' address is his "state of legal residence" and he uses it on tax forms, for insurance (he works remotely now), etc.

I'm guessing after a year or so de-facto state of legal residence changes (even though he has a history of moving often), and he should use his physical address on tax forms, insurance, and everything else.  Is he right, or am I right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better asked on https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch - I asked for a general answer, using insurance and taxes as examples.  Even if I were to have focused just on taxes, the people at money.se aren't lawyers and don't know tax law.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch This is an issue about tax law and other related legal issues, and while it would be on topic on the Money stack, seems at least as much on topic here. It should not be closed as off-topic.If closed for that reason, I will vote to reopen.

Comment: *"... the people at money.se aren't lawyers and don't know tax law."* So, you've not actually been to that site or read any of the posts there. They have thousands of questions dealing with tax of various sorts, and this is exactly the kind of question they answer.